# How can light penetrate gold in an astronaut's visor?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light

Astronaut visors use a thin gold layer to decrease intensity of IR radiation coming from the sun. The thing is, gold is a conductive surface, so how can it transmit light through it. Is this related to the skin effect, where an AC current running through a wire will cause current to build up of surface of the wire?

Comment: What does gold being a conductor matter? If conductors of arbitrary thinness blocked arbitrary EM radiation then metal foil would be the perfect radiation shield...

Comment: How much light is absorbed by one gold atom? How about two? There is a skin depth, and if a gold layer is thinner than the skin depth then you have transmission.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Sufficiently thin gold films are not opaque but green:](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Marcos-Nobre/post/The-Color-of-the-coating-is-changed-with-the-thickness-What-is-reason-behind-this/attachment/59d62e6479197b807798c985/AS%3A354068301139968%401461427869572/download/ColoursMetallicFilms.pdf)

[image]

This is near the percolation threshold at which clumps or islands of atoms join to form a continuous opaque film. See also Norrman et al. (1978). "Optical properties of discontinuous gold films," *Phys Rev B* **18**, 674, and Turner, T. (1908). "Transparent silver and other metallic films," *Proc R Soc Lond A*, **81**, 301–310, and the references within. As noted, [Michael Faraday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Faraday) may have been the first to report this behavior, realized by inspecting through-illuminated beaten metal films.